# Convert url to fixed text, but still clickable -- Android

Tags: android, textview

I get messages, but some of them looks like this:

http://x.x.x.x:8080/DocumentViewer/viewer.html?.......

I want to "filter" this messages to convert in somthing like: "Media Message.Click to open", to hide the url. But I need to make this text clickable , and open the "hidden" url.

I found that I can do with the property "autoLink=web" in the TextView, setting as a web: `<a href="link">TEXT</a>`  but it don't work, or I'm making something bad.

What I have is something like:

```
if (mess.getBodyMessage().contains("DocumentViewer")) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.append("<a href=\"" + mess.getBodyMessage() + "\">" + "Media Message.Click to open" + "</a>");
   mess.setBodyMessage(sb.toString());
}
```

And then in the view:

```
<xx.xx.xx.view.text.FontTextView
            android:id="@+id/message_scout_text_text_view_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/text_navy"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:font="museo_sans_500.otf"
            tools:text="test"/>
```

But as I said, don't work

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try it using SpannableString

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
String myString = "Some text [clickable]";
int i1 = myString.indexOf("[");
int i2 = myString.indexOf("]");
myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
myTextView.setText(myString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable mySpannable = (Spannable)myTextView.getText();
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
{
 @Override
 public void onClick(View widget) { /* do something */ }
};
mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, i1, i2 + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
private void stripUnderlines(TextView textView) {
        Spannable s = new SpannableString(textView.getText());
        URLSpan[] spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span: spans) {
            int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
            s.removeSpan(span);
            span = new URLSpanNoUnderline(span.getURL());
            s.setSpan(span, start, end, 0);
        }
        textView.setText(s);
    }
```

> override class

```
private class URLSpanNoUnderline extends URLSpan {
        public URLSpanNoUnderline(String url) {
            super(url);
        }
        @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    }
```